# HAProxy listen with two arguments?

Tags: haproxy, documentation

I keep seeing HAProxy configuration examples with a two-argument syntax. Indeed, the default configuration file supplied with 1.4.18 contains this:

```
listen  appli1-rewrite 0.0.0.0:10001
    cookie  SERVERID rewrite
    balance roundrobin
    server  app1_1 192.168.34.23:8080 cookie app1inst1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
    server  app1_2 192.168.34.32:8080 cookie app1inst2 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
    server  app1_3 192.168.34.27:8080 cookie app1inst3 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
    server  app1_4 192.168.34.42:8080 cookie app1inst4 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
```

I am noticing a complete lack of any bind option, so am I to believe that this is a shorthand for bind?

The HAProxy documentation (http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt) contains one unrelated example with this syntax, but does not specify, document or explain it anywhere.

The documentation simply shows `listen   <name>`:

```
All proxy names must be formed from upper and lower case letters, digits,
'-' (dash), '_' (underscore) , '.' (dot) and ':' (colon). ACL names are
case-sensitive, which means that "www" and "WWW" are two different proxies.
```

(i.e. no spaces, so this clearly isn't just part of the name)

Is there any official documentation for this syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: This is confusing the hell out of me too. It seems almost completely undocumented syntax, so why is it so commonly used?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I just cracked this by finding [this answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1092793/104997).  In HAProxy 1.3.x, [the deprecated reference manual](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.3/doc/haproxy-en.txt) said:

```
2) Declaration of a listening service
=====================================

Service sections start with the 'listen' keyword :

    listen <instance_name> [ <IP_address>:<port_range>[,...] ]
```

[By 1.4, this manual no longer existed](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.4/doc/), but it seems that this syntax continued to be accepted for backwards compatibility.  In 1.6, a `listen` section without a `bind` directive [started to generate warnings](http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy.git;a=commit;h=f3934b8c6d85).

So the answer is that it's old syntax which shouldn't be used any more.